# Got an issue converting a short[] into a bitmap which class should I be using?

Tags: c#, bitmap, short, heightmap

need help converting this short[] into a grayscale bmp
Current Error : http://grabilla.com/04c0f-dcadafc9-1274-4cbf-a3a9-dc47d5148c25.html#
the tdata array is a short[]  or list< int16>its short grayscale height map

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ConvertSHTtobmp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int h, w;
        h = 1536;
        w = 1536;
        List<byte> tdata = new List<byte>();


        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("C:\\Users\\Keith\\Desktop\\StartZone_1536_1536_0.sht", FileMode.Open)))
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
                {
                    byte temp = br.ReadByte();
                    tdata.Add (temp);

                    temp = br.ReadByte();
                    tdata.Add(temp);


                }
            }

            CreateBitmapFromBytes(tdata.ToArray(), w, h);

        }

    }

    private static void CreateBitmapFromBytes(byte[] pixelValues, int width, int height)
    {
        //Create an image that will hold the image data
        Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);

        //Get a reference to the images pixel data
        Rectangle dimension = new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height);
        BitmapData picData = pic.LockBits(dimension, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pic.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr pixelStartAddress = picData.Scan0;

        //Copy the pixel data into the bitmap structure
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelValues, 0, pixelStartAddress,    pixelValues.Length);

        pic.UnlockBits(picData);
        pic.Save(@"C:\Users\Keith\Desktop\heightmap.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }


}


}
```

Comment: What exception do you observe?

Comment: @dymanoid http://grabilla.com/04c0e-de6f9af6-5f04-4ac6-aae7-085eeb6a2feb.html#

Comment: The `BitmapSource.Create()` method accepts an array of `byte`, but you pass an array of `short`. This may be the reason.

Comment: ok so using your little idea i fked with it a little more and got this 
http://grabilla.com/04c0f-f541a051-18c6-4efa-9abc-dc1810d003f4.html#

then i was able to generate this but the output is wrong any chance you know how i can fix the colors to make it true grayscale ? 

this is how it came out its also in the wrong aspect ratio its 
suposed to be 1576 by 1576 and it is but all the data is squeezed into the left half side of the image i checked the array and its equivalent to 1536^2*2

Comment: http://grabilla.com/04c0f-209ecf18-2aa9-401b-b28f-2cb64ea24ead.html#

it should be able to fit over the image on the right they are same resolution and its actually the attribute map for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10252c05-c4b6-49dc-b2a3-4c1396e2c3ab/writing-a-16bit-grayscale-image?forum=csharpgeneral

finally found the right search terms after a few hours of searching :)

ok so the above link got me thinking about the following stuff.

the end solution was this

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.IO;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
  public partial class Window1 : Window
  {
    public Window1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      short[] Buf = new short[64 * 64];
      BitmapSource bmpSrc = BitmapSource.Create(
        64, 64, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray16, null, Buf, 128);
      TransformedBitmap transformedBmp = new TransformedBitmap(bmpSrc, new RotateTransform(-90));
      PngBitmapEncoder enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
      enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(transformedBmp));
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\Temp\\Test.png", FileMode.Create))
      {
        enc.Save(fs);
      }
    }
   }
   }
```

sources:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1a0919e9-95df-4479-95b8-103e1914e08e/problems-saving-a-12bpp-short-array-as-a-grayscale-bmp?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: if you can fix this issue then ill give you the vote
http://grabilla.com/04c0f-dcadafc9-1274-4cbf-a3a9-dc47d5148c25.html#
 that script unfortunatly didnt work i get a gdi error